# Can I use VBA in Excel 2010 Starter Edition?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the MS-Excel 2010 "Starter Edition" - it comes bundled into pre-built PCs.

Does this edition support VBA macros?  I cannot tell.

I searched and I am still not clear on this.

Comment: If you get the VBA editor when you hold down Alt-F11 then the answer is yes.  I'm guessing it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't use VBA in starter edition. It's one of the features that are disabled. It's available in the Standard or Premium editions.